# Is $[-1, 1]$ really uncountable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I read many times that $[-1,1]$ is an uncountable set.
But if I do a Fourier transform of a continous waveform drawn into $[-1,1]$, I get an infinite discrete spectrum which seems to be countable as $\mathbb Z$ is.

Thanks !

EDIT : I know that it's uncountable, but where is my mistake ? The cardinality of my waveform seems to be the same as the cardinality of $[-1,1]$, as The cardinality of my spectrum seems to be the same as the cardinality of $\mathbb Z$. And Fourier is a bijection.

Comment: Why would that contradict the uncountability of $[-1,1]$?

Comment: The function $f(x)=1$ maps the entire real line to a single number, and yet, the real line is uncountable.

Comment: Why should there be a bijective correspondence between points on  [-1,1] and Fourier spectrum? There are a lot more functions on [-1,1] than convergent sums of waveforms, those discontinuous everywhere or Lebesgue non-measurable.

Comment: The fact you've cited about Fourier transforms has nothing to do with the cardinality of $[-1, 1]$ - are you sure you understand what the statement "$[-1, 1]$ is uncountable" means in the first place?

Comment: I get as many numbers as there are in [-1,1] to describe my waveform.
I get as many numbers as there are in Z to describe my spectrum.

Comment: *One* waveform can be described by countably many numbers, it is true. But so what? A continuous function on $[-1,1]$ can also be described by its values on a countable dense subset, like $[-1,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$. That doesn't break the uncountability, it just says that you didn't really need to know the value of your waveform at every point in order to know what the waveform is. And that is because we have implicitly assumed here that the waveform is "nice" in some sense, for instance Lebesgue measurable and square integrable.

Comment: What exactly is confusing about this? A wave can be expressed as a countable collection real numbers, but the real numbers come from an uncountable set.

Comment: In particular, a single waveform does not have a cardinality. There is one waveform. What are you trying to count about it?

Comment: Building on Ian's comment: note that already one *real number* can *already* be described by countably much information (namely, its decimal expansion). Try to make things concrete: can you turn your picture into an explicit bijection between $[-1, 1]$ and $\mathbb{N}$? If not, why not? If you think about the obstacle for a while, you'll see what's going on (which is that your observation doesn't really have anything to do with the problem).

Comment: @lan : a square is not a continous function for exemple.

Comment: @user2443456 I am aware that there are discontinuous square integrable waveforms. My bringing up continuous functions was as an analogy to another case where specifying countably many real numbers specifies an element of a seemingly rather large set. Noah's point is actually even better: countably many selections from a *finite* set is enough to specify an element of $[-1,1]$, which is nevertheless uncountable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you misunderstand what it means to say that Fourier transform is one-to-one. It means that if $f$ and $g$ are two essentially different functions (i.e. the measure of the set of values of $x$ for which $f(x)\ne g(x)$ is more than $0$) then the Fourier transforms of $f$ and $g$ are different. Note that it says different **functions,** not different values of $x.$

Comment: So does it means that less numbers in my spectrum contains the same quantity of information than all the numbers describing my waveform in [-1,1] ? If so, it's really weird.

Comment: @user2443456 It's not as weird as it sounds. Michael's answer actually points out a key phenomenon: by choosing not to distinguish between functions that are equal almost everywhere, you wind up reducing the set of Lebesgue measurable functions, which has larger cardinality than $\mathbb{R}$, down to a set whose cardinality is the same as $\mathbb{R}$. When you do make such distinctions the Fourier transform is no longer one-to-one.

Comment: @user2443456 : Perhaps it is somewhat weird, but it can be viewed as follows: Call two functions $f,g$ equivalent if the measure of the set of points $x$ for which $f(x)\ne g(x)$ is $0.$ Then, although there are many functions, there are few equivalence classes. (A smaller infinite cardinality.) Each equivalence class is big, so there don't need to be as many of them.

Answer (score 2):

Your argument is that if $f:S\to\mathbb{C}$ has Fourier transform $\tilde{f}:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{C}$, then there is a bijection between $S$ and $\mathbb{Z}$.

You try to argue for the existence of such a bijection by saying the Fourier transform operator $F$ that sends $f$ to $\tilde{f}$ is bijective.

But the domain of $F$ isn't $S$, and the range of $F$ isn't $\mathbb{Z}$. The Fourier transform gives a bijection between a certain set of equivalence classes **of** functions and another set **of** functions; it does not give a bijection between the sets the functions themselves are defined **on**.